# Is there a way to test with if for a position field of a skspritenode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

like this

```
if enemy.position.x == 1 to 200 && enemy.position.y == 1 to 200 {
    //do sth
}
```

so it should run the code if the enemy is in field of x: 1 - 200, y: 1 - 200.

can someone please help me thanks ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contains` with a `ClosedRange`:

```
if (1...200).contains(enemy.position.x) && (1...200).contains(enemy.position.y) {
    // do sth
}
```

or you can use `~=`:

```
if 1...200 ~= enemy.position.x && 1...200 ~= enemy.position.y {
    // do sth
}
```